# Entity Framework - Set timeout for linq statement

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there any option in EF to set timeout for a specific linq statement, just like in nhibernate. 
For example I would like to do something like:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext("TestDbContext"))
{
    var query = context.TestItems.AsQueryable().Where(x=> x.Price > 6);
    query.Timeout(120);
    var results = query.ToList();
}
```